# ANRs & crashes (help to read log)

Tags: android

I did my first app(called Tumch in Google Play if someone wants to search it kk) and has few users, most of the users use the app with no problems, but there are users crashing.

That is the log on Play console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java:0)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at android.util.Log.println_native_inner(Native Method:0)
  at android.util.Log.println_native(Log.java:290)
  at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:323)
  at example.mostliked.UserPage.onCreate(Unknown Source:0)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
```

What does it mean? How can I solve that problem? Cause in tests in my phones I didn't find errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're feeding a null String to Log.d.

Try adding a null check before logging, ex:

```
Log.d(TAG, objectToLog == null ? "null" : objectToLog.toString());
```

You might also just consider removing, pro-guarding, or commenting out logs for the production build.